# How to get accumulated view count of YouTube video during a period?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can I get a YouTube video's view counts during a period. For example, I entered a date and the result showed that the accumulated view counts from the uploaded date to the date I entered. How can it realized?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the **Youtube Reporting API** which contains a lot of metrics, such as [views](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/metrics#views), [likes](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/metrics#likes), and [average_view_duration_seconds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/metrics#average_view_duration_seconds).

> **`views`** (core metric)
>
> The number of times that a video was viewed. In a playlist report, the
>   metric indicates the number of times that a video was viewed in the
>   context of a playlist. The [YouTube Help Center](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1714329?ref_topic=1714326&guide=1714169) provides additional
>   information about how views are reported. This is a core metric and is
>   subject to the [Deprecation Policy](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/subject-api-services).

Comment: It seems that only can see **MY** uploaded video's statistics. But I want to see the videos' that other users uploaded.

Comment: If that's the case, you can check this youtube tutorial - [Super Easy Way View Analytics on Any Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqcaVCBwMB8).

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. That tool can't get it. It can only get whole channel's current total view...